# Two uncountable noun connected by "and"

Tags: nouns, subject-verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns

> Water and air is essential to us.

Or

> Water and air are essential to us.

Which one is correct? Because there are two element, should I use *are*. But they are both uncountable, should I use *is*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have two uncountable nouns connected by "and" you are still talking about plural things, so use the plural copula (or verb):

> Water and air **are** essential to us.